# Apache Redirect from a folder to a index.php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rules

I want to redirect from `http://www.domain.com/customer1 to /app/index.php?c=customer1` and `http://www.domain.com/customer2 to /app/index.php?c=customer2`

I tried the below rule but not works well...

```
RewriteRule ^customer1(.*)$ /app/index.php?c=customer1
```

Comment: I want to open http://www.domain.com/customer1 and apache redirects to: **http://www.domain.com/app/index.php?c=customer_code**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about rewriting,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ /app/index.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will internally rewrite your urls if not rewriting then try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RerwiteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ /app/index.php?c=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This not working... I want to open http://www.domain.com/customer1 and apache redirects to: **http://www.domain.com/app/index.php?c=customer_code**

Comment: Did you tried the both rule and what do you want redirect or rewrite?

Comment: rewrite is better, I already have the below rule and workers well.  Actually the rule **RewriteRule ^customer1(.*)$ /app/index.php?c=9898373c7484(customer number)** so the redirection should be from a "customer name" to "customer number" without the customer can see his "number"